# getting error while using aws to host my django website

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to host my Django project with AWS. I have successfully made an ec2 instance on AWS  and when I have executed the required commands on my Linux cmd it works perfectly.I have uploaded my required project on it which is as shown below

```
(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~$ ls
en2  final_webpage  req.txt  var
```

var is the virtual environment that I have created during my project.final_webpage is my project which I have to execute.

```
(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage$ cd form
(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage/form$ ls
db.sqlite3  en1  form  manage.py  pip3  subform
```

when I am trying to run my manage.py it is showing an error.

```
(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage/form$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/final_webpage/form/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/final_webpage/form/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/final_webpage/form/manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

this is my python version which I am using

```
(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage/form$ python3
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 01:15:05) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

the same project when I am trying to run on my normal cmd it works perfectly fine

```
astirmind@astirmind-H61H2-M4:~/desktop$ cd final_webpage
astirmind@astirmind-H61H2-M4:~/desktop/final_webpage$ cd form
astirmind@astirmind-H61H2-M4:~/desktop/final_webpage/form$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 05, 2022 - 10:36:18
Django version 3.2.9, using settings 'form.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

can anyone suggest me something

Comment: Have you installed your requirements? `python3 -m pip install -r req.txt`

Comment: yes i have installed that

Comment: ```(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage/form$ python3
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 01:15:05) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
```  this is my python version but when i am trying to install django int it

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` Are you sure there is a `django` in `req.txt`?

Comment: So you can `import django` in that shell successfully?

Comment: ```(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage/form$ pip3 install django==3.2.9
-bash: /home/ubuntu/var/bin/pip3: /home/ubuntu/var/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory``` this is what am getting
``

Comment: Use `python3 -m pip` not `pip3`. Where did that `pip3` file in your project directory come from?

Comment: ```(var) ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-19:~/final_webpage$ python3 -m pip install django==3.2.9
```and now this is what am getting

Comment: ```File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/__init__.py)
```

Comment: i can't type full error here due to word limitation this is the last one

Comment: ```ubuntu@ip-172-31-94-21:~/final_webpage/form$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig
```now i am getting this error

Comment: `File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango41Warning
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 5, in <module>
    from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 115
    launch_map: "Dict[asyncio.Task[object], threading.Thread]" = {}
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`